# How to get the JavaScript split() method to split pasted text properly by new lines?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please help with this?

I have some contenteditable div elements. I need to add the option of copy/pasting numbers into them. These numbers can be in columns and rows, like in excel.

The pasted text must be split first by newlines and then each line afterwards by space/tab so that into the div element comes only the top left number. The rest of the numbers should then go into the subsequent div elements, like in excel.

```js
const target = document.querySelector("div#input11");

target.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {

  let paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/plain');
  var pasteString = paste.toString();
  result = stringOperations(pasteString);

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
  selection.deleteFromDocument();
  selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(result));

  event.preventDefault();

});

function stringOperations(s) {

  var rowArray = s.split("/(\n\r|\n|\r)/gm");
  return rowArray[0];

}
```

```html
<div id="input11" class="input-field2" contenteditable="true" onChange="checkInput(1,1)"></div>
```

The problem is that my RegEx expression doesn't seem to recognize new lines so that he pasted text isn't being split by new lines.

When I copy/paste this into the div :

```
44439 515 541 928
43936 929 692 711
44464 800 710 824
41533 979 675 758
```

I just get the numbers as a long sequence, separated by space instead of the first line only.

```
44439 515 541 928 43936 929 692 711 44464 800 710 824 41533 979 675 758
```

I much appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has quotes, while it shouldn't have them. Change `"/(\n\r|\n|\r)/gm"` to simply `/(\n\r|\n|\r)/gm` and you should be good to go.

```js
const target = document.querySelector("div#input11");

target.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {

  let paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/plain');
  var pasteString = paste.toString();
  result = stringOperations(pasteString);

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
  selection.deleteFromDocument();
  selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(result));

  event.preventDefault();

});

function stringOperations(s) {
  var rowArray = s.split(/(\n\r|\n|\r)/gm);
  return rowArray[0];
}
```

```html
<div id="input11" class="input-field2" contenteditable="true" onChange="checkInput(1,1)"></div>
```